How to avoid an type assumption in typeguard of string union type
I have this construction very often:
const itemList = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;
type ItemType = typeof itemList[number];
const typeGuard = (thing: string): thing is ItemType => itemList.includes(thing);

The last lien throws an error: itemList can only contain 'a', 'b', 'c', to i can not thow anything else to includes.
So I have to do
const typeGuard = (thing: string): thing is ItemType => (itemList as readonly string[]).includes(thing);


Isn't it ironic that I have to introduce a type assumption in order to mainatain type safety? Is there a better solution?

It's not an assumption or assertion, it's a widening, which should be absolutely fine
